# Inkscape + Beamer for slideshows

Tags: inkscape, animation, workflow, automation, presentation

So I have tried using JessyInk for slideshows and found it rather underwhelming, but I love the idea of being able to make slides in inkscape. I am a physicist who is making scientific presentations, so I want something relatively simple and conservative.

Currently my hacked together method involves making a separate inkscape file for each slide, I output to pdfs and then insert the slides into a presentation using LaTex's Beamer . This lets me leverage latex for simple mathy slides, and use Inkscape for more graphic ones.

My only stumbling block is doing transitions between slides. Currently I make a base slide, make a copy, add the next element, make another copy, add another element, and so on.

There must be a better way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you had a look at Sozi? (http://sozi.baierouge.fr/) You only need a single SVG file (from Inkscape) for it, and it's quite fun. Presentations work in a web browser. For exporting layers as pdf pages, there's an Inkscape extension, that would make the process a bit faster: https://gitlab.com/su-v/inx-exportobjects

Comment: Hey Moini, 

Yes I looked at Sozi. I should say this is for scientific (physics) presentations (I will change the post to reflect this), and I found Sozi a little dizzying. Physicists are pretty conservative, and the feedback from audience members tends to be that they like simple transitions with as little animation as possible. 

I really want something that lets you export multiple PDFs from one SVG file. Maybe you can export one layer to PDF at a time for instance. 

Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Hey Moini, 

I rubber ducked you. The layer solution works exactly how I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out an easy solution.

1. Define n-layers: one layer per transition slide.
2. In each layer include all the elements you want to show up simultaneously. Make sure that all objects are within the canvas since we will be relying on the canvas to provide a consistent slide size.
3. When you want to export the slide pdfs click Layer-> Show/hide Current Layer to hide a toggle between layers being visible or hidden.
4. When you have a slide configuration you like click File->Save a Copy and make sure you use the document's page size. Export to an appropriately named pdf.

This can probably be scripted to automate the process, I will post again if I figure out how to do that (and I am happy to hear suggestions from others)